# Laravel : How to Log INFO/ERROR to separate file

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, monolog

How to separate error and info into different files in laravel5.5?
This is  my code in  `bootstrap/app.php`
But errors will appear in both `error.log` and `lumen.log`

```
$app->configureMonologUsing(function (\Monolog\Logger $monolog) use ($app) {
    $handlerError = new \Monolog\Handler\RotatingFileHandler(storage_path('logs/error.log'), $app->make('config')->get('app.log_max_files', 5), \Monolog\Logger::ERROR);
    $handlerInfo = new \Monolog\Handler\RotatingFileHandler(storage_path('logs/lumen.log'), $app->make('config')->get('app.log_max_files', 5), \Monolog\Logger::INFO);
    $monolog->pushHandler($handlerError);
    $monolog->pushHandler($handlerInfo);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Log::useFiles('path/to/file.log');
Log::info('Info');
```

you can also refer this laravel link https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Log/Writer.html

Comment: thank you for your reply， I know this 。 This is more troublesome to use....